# what is ".responsive" in css? Is this a predefined css functionality because in below mentioned code we did not specify responsive class in html

Tags: css, responsive-design, navbar, responsive

In below mentioned code we are using ".responsive" but we have not mentioned "responsive" class in HTML how are we accessing it in css using ".responsive" do we have this predefined in css? how is this working?

```
      enter code here
      <style>
      @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
      .topnav.responsive .icon {
       position: absolute;
       }
       .topnav.responsive a {
       float: none;
       display: block;
       }
      .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
      .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
      .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
       display: block;
       width: 100%;
       text-align: left;
       }
     }
    </style>
    <body>
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
      <a href="#news">News</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        </div>
      </div> 
      <a href="#about">About</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" 
     onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
    </div>
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
      if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
      } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
      }
        }
       </script>
       </body>
```

Comment: The `responsive` class is being added via your script at the bottom of the doc. There is no default `responsive` class. If that class is doing anything for you then it is coming in from a difference source, but as is, it does nothing.